# Making sense of scatter plots

Tags: regression, data-visualization

I had a recent question which I probably should re-formulate to a more general one.

I came across this: [Using scatter plots to understand multiple values of Y for a given X](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50160/using-scatter-plots-to-understand-multiple-values-of-y-for-a-given-x) and thought the accepted answer was very good, but what's unclear to me is: given a nasty scatter plot, how would you visually get the idea what sort of relationship the x:es and y:s have? In my mind, there's no way of telling if a linear, quadratic, etc regression is appropriate.

If we look at the plot that is currently confounding me:
[image: scatterplot]

My idea was to somehow plot the AVERAGE of f(x), with x clumped together in intervals, instead of each observation. Is this how you would go about it? If not, what other way do you visually make sense of this data?

Comment: Just an observation on your particular plot, but the y values appear to fixed at integer intervals. If the y values are known to be accurate you only need regression on the x values. Or to look at it another way, as in Glen_b's bins example, you already have bins. I'm no expert on this stuff though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider a [lowess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression) (/loess) or similar local smooth.

consider:

[image]

This one was generated in R with `scatter.smooth`. It's an estimate of the local mean, but in a way that they vary smoothly; directly akin to using a kernel density estimate instead of a histogram.

If you must have bins, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51840/rationale-for-the-use-of-regressogram-bin-smooth/51843#51843) which describes how to do something like this regressogram (bin smoother):

[image: regressogram of mcycle data]

Comment: Very interesting! I think your answer in the other question was what I was looking for here aswell though.

Comment: +1 - a slight amount of jitter and making the points smaller and semi-transparent in the original plot would make it more informative as well (which takes minimal data manipulation). I can't figure out the precision of the values on the x-axis - but they already appear to be "clumped together" as the circles overlap exactly.

Comment: @AndyW By 'original plot', I presume you mean the one in the question (I didn't attempt to reproduce that aspect of the x-variable); I agree completely with your thoughts about making the plot more informative.

Comment: Yes I meant the plot in Benjamin's question.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is called 2d density. [Here are some examples](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/2d-density-chart/) in R and ggplot. [Contouring in ggplot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density_2d.html). I recently needed contouring including expected joint distribution so here is example code in R.

```
 ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = wt)) + stat_density2d () + 
stat_density_2d(mapping = aes(x = mtcars$hp[sample(1:length(mtcars$hp))], y = mtcars$wt), color = "green",
geom = "density_2d", position = "identity" , contour = TRUE, n = 100, h = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = F, inherit.aes = F)
```